# Node.js - Testing REST API routes with supertest

Tags: node.js, rest, supertest

Req.body is not accessible in the routes while making a post request. It would be highly appreciative of someone if he/she help me getting through it. Here is screenshot of my microservice.test.js file. Am I missing something?

```
import request from "supertest";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import config from "../config/env";
import routes from "../server/routes";

import { parseResponse, doRequest } from "../server/utils/helperFunctions";

const app = express();
app.use("/", routes);

jest.setTimeout(30000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided doesn't provide much insight, as I would expect all of the handling of the request to be in your route handler.  Is the issue that you are unable to access the body when running tests with `supertest`?  Or that it isn't working at all.  More information would be very helpful.

If it is a `supertest` issue, I would recommend checking out [the docs for good examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest).  Here is one I pulled directly from the NPM site where they POST some data with a request body and then verify the response body:

```
describe('POST /user', function() {
  it('user.name should be an case-insensitive match for "john"', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/user')
      .send('name=john') // x-www-form-urlencoded upload
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(function(res) {
        res.body.id = 'some fixed id';
        res.body.name = res.body.name.toLowerCase();
      })
      .expect(200, {
        id: 'some fixed id',
        name: 'john'
      }, done);
  });
});
```

Also, if you are trying to test your server you should probably import your server code instead of creating a new express instance.  For example, in your server code you'll have something like this:

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use('/', ...) // middleware/route config
...

module.exports = app;
```

Your server would then use this server like this:

`index.js`

```
const app = require('./server')
const port = 4000

app.listen({ port }, () => {
  const location = `http://localhost:${port}`
  logger.info(` Server ready at ${location}`)
})

module.exports = app
```

Now that you have structured your code this way, in your test you can import your server as well (so you are testing your actual server, not a new server that you made up):

`server.test.js`

```
const app = require('../../../server');
const request = require('supertest')(app);

describe('Server', () => {
  it('does a thing', async () => {
    const { body } = await request
      .post('http://path/to/test')
      .send({ data: 'some data' })
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(200);

    expect(body.thing).toBeTrue();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

expressjs version lower than 4  include body parsing middleware

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
app.use(bodyParser());
```

example test

```
it('.post should work with data', function (done) {
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser());

    app.post('/', function(req, res){
      res.send(req.body.name);
    });

    request(app)
    .post('/')
    .send({ name: 'tobi' })
    .expect('tobi', done);
  })
```

Comment: I think a person answering this sort of question must be in the same university/office :)